# How to display same data points in a same series in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

How to display the same data points in the same series in highcharts ?

Please refer below example

https://jsfiddle.net/skoormala/1wq603rs/3/

```
series: [{
    name: 'Property',
    data: [{"name":"Property 1", "x":1,"y":2}, 
     **{"name":"Property 2", "x":2,"y":5}**,
     **{"name":"Property 5", "x":2,"y":5},**
     {"name":"Property 3", "x":3,"y":6},
      {"name":"Property 4", "x":4,"y":8}]
}]
```

In the above series property 2 and property 5 has the same  coordinates please advise how to display them in a tooltip on mouse hover

Answer (score 1):

The `tooltip.shared` property works only for points with different series, for a single series you can use the `pointFormatter` function to build a tooltip according to your requirements, for example:

```
    tooltip: {
        pointFormatter: function() {
            const x = this.x,
                y = this.y;
            const points = this.series.points.filter(p => p.x === x && p.y === y);
            const pointNames = points.reduce(
                (result, point) => ((result ? result + ', ' : '') + point.name),
                ''
            );

            return pointNames + '<br/>' + 'x: ' + x + '<br/>y: ' + y
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/og2jwms0/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormatter

Comment: Hi,
How to add the scrollbar in tooltip

https://jsfiddle.net/uyj18zm9/6/

Comment: Hello @Satyanarayana, I will answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66793533/how-to-set-scrollbar-in-highchart-tooltip