# How to set scrollbar in highchart tooltip?

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to scatter chart tooltip with scrollbar, Please refer to the above jsfiddle and provide solution.

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/uyj18zm9/6/`
```

Comment: how to add scrollbar for tooltip in the given Highchart sample https://jsfiddle.net/uyj18zm9/6/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add style `overflow-y: scroll` and set some height.

```
tooltipString = '<div class="..." style="...; height: 80px; overflow-y: scroll">';
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fo6jm7gL/

**CSS overflow-y:** https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp

Comment: Thank you for your reference. but I am unable to scroll. Please find the below example 

In this example, I have removed  "stickOnContact: true" property, because I have lost the smoothness of the cursor movement.

https://jsfiddle.net/p2ekjvhz/2/

Please suggest me any other way?

Comment: Hi @Satyanarayana, Add `pointerEvents: 'auto'` to the styles. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9Lm0evs5/